# Wishes are mean/meant to be true

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Wishes are mean/meant to be true.
Mean or Meant, which is more appropriate?

Comment: Look, this is a passive form, you should use the past form of the verb *mean* (which in this case is *meant*).

Answer (score 2):

"Wishes are meant to be true" is grammatical, though nonsensical. "Wishes are mean to be true" is only nonsensical.

I suppose you are really aiming for "Wishes are meant to come true". Even that, of course, is debatable, but that is a question to pass on to philosophers.

Answer (score 0):

The grammatically correct answer would be "meant".

"Meant" is the past tense and past participle of "mean".

Let's swap out "meant" for another word, "supposed".

"Wishes are supposed to be true." would be grammatically correct while "Wishes are suppose to be true." isn't.

This last part will not be answering the question, but wishes aren't necessarily meant to be true.